# Author calls factors $(x+1-\sqrt2)(x+1+\sqrt2)$ "rational so far as $x$ is concerned". What does this mean?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I'm reading *Elementary Algebra* by Rouse W. W. Ball, and factorization strategies for quadratics are being discussed.

In the book, we are trying to factor $x^2+2x-1$, so we complete the square

$$x^2+2x-1$$
$$=(x^2+2x+1)-1-1$$
$$=(x+1)^2-2$$

But the author doesn't stop there; he says that we can use difference of squares to factor this further.

$$a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$$
And thus our equation becomes
$$(x+1-\sqrt2)(x+1+\sqrt2)$$

> But what bothers me is that the author then says: "These factors are rational so far as $x$ is concerned." I have no idea what this means.
>
> Aren't these factors *irrational* since $\sqrt2$ is involved?

Comment: What does the author say after that?

Comment: He moves on to how to complete the square when the coefficient of $x^2$ is not 1, i.e., on quadratics of the form $ax^2+bx+c$ (not $x^2+bx+c$)

Comment: My best guess is that he's trying to say there's nothing irrational attached to $x$ as a coefficient. Although admittedly I'm not sure why that would be important ^_^

Comment: I agree with you. I don't know why that would be important either.

Comment: Perhaps „it is a product of polynomials in $x$“ as opposed to „it involves square roots of polynomials in $x$“?